# How to ensure old password is cleared out and new one generated on button click

Tags: javascript, random, passwords, generator

I am trying to create a random password generator which I have got working. But each time I click the button, rather than clearing the old one and generating new random passwords, it adds to the one that was there previously. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong please? I am a newbie by the way.

Here is what I have done after watching tutorials to get it working. When I remove the `+=` which I thought would fix it, it then generates one letter at a time and continues to add rather than replace with each button click.

```js
let chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "!", "@", "£", "$", "%", "^", "(", ")"]

let passwordEl1 = document.querySelector("#password-el1")
let passwordEl2 = document.querySelector("#password-el2")
let passwordEl3 = document.querySelector("#password-el3")
let passwordEl4 = document.querySelector("#password-el4")

let passwordLength = 5 // 

function generatePassword() {
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    randomStr1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)

    passwordEl1.textContent += chars[randomStr1]
    passwordEl2.textContent += chars[randomStr2]
    passwordEl3.textContent += chars[randomStr3]
    passwordEl4.textContent += chars[randomStr4]

  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="heading-sec">
    <h1>Generate a <br> Random password</h1>
    <p>Never use an insecure password again.</p>
    <button onclick="generatePassword()">Generate Password</button>
    <span onclick="copy()">Copy</span>
    <hr>
  </div id="heading-sec">

  <div id="password-container">
    <div id="password-block">
      <p class="password" id="password-el1"></p>
      <p class="password" id="password-el2"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="password-block">
      <p class="password" id="password-el3"></p>
      <p class="password" id="password-el4"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `passwordEl1.textContent = ""` before the loop

Comment: Ohh that has fixed it. So I guess that is just setting it to an empty string before generating the random code which makes sense. Thank you so much, much appreciated.

Comment: Yes because when you're doing the `+=` you are concatening strings

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of each of the variables for the passwords to be blank at the beginning of the generatePassword() function so every time it is clicked, it 0's it out.

```
let chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "!", "@", "£", "$", "%", "^", "(", ")"]

let passwordEl1 = document.querySelector("#password-el1")
let passwordEl2 = document.querySelector("#password-el2")
let passwordEl3 = document.querySelector("#password-el3")
let passwordEl4 = document.querySelector("#password-el4")

let passwordLength = 5 // 

function generatePassword() {
    passwordEl1.textContent = ""
    passwordEl2.textContent = ""
    passwordEl3.textContent = ""
    passwordEl4.textContent = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    randomStr1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)

    passwordEl1.textContent += chars[randomStr1]
    passwordEl2.textContent += chars[randomStr2]
    passwordEl3.textContent += chars[randomStr3]
    passwordEl4.textContent += chars[randomStr4]

  }
}
```

Everything put together.

```js
let chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "!", "@", "£", "$", "%", "^", "(", ")"]

let passwordEl1 = document.querySelector("#password-el1")
let passwordEl2 = document.querySelector("#password-el2")
let passwordEl3 = document.querySelector("#password-el3")
let passwordEl4 = document.querySelector("#password-el4")

let passwordLength = 5 // 

function generatePassword() {
    passwordEl1.textContent = ""
    passwordEl2.textContent = ""
    passwordEl3.textContent = ""
    passwordEl4.textContent = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    randomStr1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    randomStr4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)

    passwordEl1.textContent += chars[randomStr1]
    passwordEl2.textContent += chars[randomStr2]
    passwordEl3.textContent += chars[randomStr3]
    passwordEl4.textContent += chars[randomStr4]

  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="heading-sec">
    <h1>Generate a <br> Random password</h1>
    <p>Never use an insecure password again.</p>
    <button onclick="generatePassword()">Generate Password</button>
    <span onclick="copy()">Copy</span>
    <hr>
  </div id="heading-sec">

  <div id="password-container">
    <div id="password-block">
      <p class="password" id="password-el1"></p>
      <p class="password" id="password-el2"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="password-block">
      <p class="password" id="password-el3"></p>
      <p class="password" id="password-el4"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's great thank you, this worked a treat and it makes sense because I wasn't resetting it to an empty string previously.